# Console error with example of ui.bootstrap.datepicker

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to use angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker and it upset me for a while with an error on firebug console (Firefox 21) saying

```
Error: array is undefined
indexOf@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:526
arrayRemove@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:535
JQLiteUnbind@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:1630
JQLite.prototype[name]@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2203
.link/<@http://localhost:9000/components/angular-ui-bootstrap-bower/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:1
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:7942
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:8143
done@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:9170
completeRequest@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:9333
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:9304

http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js
Line 5754
```

After I check every datepicker settings I check the given example in documentation, followed the link "edit it on plunker" and I got a similar error.

```
Error: array is undefined
indexOf@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:510
arrayRemove@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:519
JQLiteUnbind@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:1596
JQLite.prototype[name]@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:2149
.link/<@http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js:1229
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:7878
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:8079
bootstrap/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:962
invoke@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:2843
bootstrap@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:961
angularInit@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:936
@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:14729
trigger@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:1723
createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:1958
forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:133
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:1957

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js
Line 5687
```

Then I try Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63 and I got a different error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at indexOf (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:510:12)
at arrayRemove (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:519:15)
at JQLiteUnbind (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:1596:7)
at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as unbind] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:2149:17)
at Object.fn (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js:1229:21)
at Object.Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:7878:27)
at Object.Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:8079:24)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:962:13
at Object.invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:2843:25)
at bootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js:960:12)
```

It works but the error message upset me a lot and I thought that was something wrong with my code.

Can I assume this is not related with example given but with some internals or is the example missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ui-bootstrap 0.5.0 has a bug,

(it tries to unbind 'focus' event handler, but handler doesn't exist)
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js#L1226

you can apply this changes
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/bf30898da27272df75f6c7ff26545ed16ebf1978

or build it directly from github

or wait for 0.6.0